# gsub to extract string before and after dots from a vector in R?

Tags: r, gsub

Please, I want to use gsub to extract strings from this vector:

```
x<-("Prayer: Lord. Have mercy on.")
```

The desired output is "Lord" and "Have mercy on" separately.

I tried `gsub('.*:(.*)','\\1',x)` but it doesn't give them separately.

Comment: You cannot extract multiple occurrences with `gsub`. This function *removes* / *replaces* found matches and returns the modified *string* ("character vector"). If you mean to get the two substrings with two different `gsub` operations, you can use https://ideone.com/AKkh3W

Comment: Yes. With two different gsub operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to get these two values separately, you can use

```r
x <- c("Prayer: Lord. Have mercy on.")
gsub("^[^:]*:\\s*([^.]+).*","\\1",x)
## => [1] "Lord"
gsub("^[^:]*:\\s*[^.]+\\.\\s*([^.]+).*","\\1",x)
## => [1] "Have mercy on"
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/4Iw9kW), [regex #1](https://regex101.com/r/hY7zlN/1) and [regex #2](https://regex101.com/r/hY7zlN/2) demos. It does not matter if you use `sub` or `gsub` with these regexps, they will work the same, although `sub` is more logical as all you need is replace the whole string with the value of the first capturing group.

*Details*

- `^` -  start of string
- `[^:]*` - zero or more chars other than `:`
- `:` - a colon
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `[^.]+` - one or more chars other than a dot
- `\.` - a dot
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `([^.]+)` -  **Capturing group 1**: one or more chars other than dots
- `.*` - the rest of the string.

Comment: I did. Would you mind to help with one more please. A little bit more complex.

Comment: Information: Requise. Urgent et important.
Pierre: (an) 11
Jacques (ct): 45
moy (m2): 9.15 m2
TP (PT CC): 24/50

Comment: I want to extract together the two arguments: 11 and 24

Comment: @Julie Try `gsub("^.*\\(an\\)\\D*(\\d+).*", "\\1", x)` and `gsub(".*:\\s*(\\d+).*", "\\1", x)`.

Comment: I wan to extract the age of pierre and the value corresponding to the perimeter which is the numerator (24)

Comment: @ I have tagged you answer

Comment: @Julie Do the [two `gsubs`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67657572/gsub-to-extract-string-before-and-after-dots-from-a-vector-in-r/67663912?noredirect=1#comment119649977_67663912) work as expected?

Answer (score 3):

You could try splitting on `\.\s*` after stripping off the leading `Prayer:` term.

```r
x <- "Prayer: Lord. Have mercy on."
parts <- strsplit(sub("^\\w+:\\s*", "", x), "\\.\\s*")[[1]]
parts

[1] "Lord"          "Have mercy on"
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It would be helpful if it was with gsub. Moreover, only one term needs to be in the output (not both). Thank you again for further helping

Comment: Doing this via `sub` seems like the hard way.